# Transform Gizmo Disappears during Animation (Blender 2.8)

Tags: transforms, gizmo

In 2.7x series, when animation was playing, the transform manipulator was visible on the active/selected object.
[image]

In 2.80, no matter what settings I pick (active tool, widget overlay etc) when the animation plays the gizmo disappears. I can of course, still transform the object with hot keys or with "tweaking" by left clicking and drag.

[image]

Question:  Is this normal?  Is this expected?  Is this a bug.

Comment: it must be a bug, on my version, which is not the latest one, it disappear during the animation but reappear as soon as it stops